# Defining Elasticsearch mapping for ingest-attachment inner field

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, attachment

I'm trying to build an application using an Elasticsearch index.
I have several "inner" fields which can contain binary data (mainly PDF), and I'm looking for the best way to define my pipeline and mapping, given the facts that:

- all fields and contents **can** be provided in several languages (french and english) and in several fields
- I have to be able to query contents for a given language and/or for a given field.

This is how I defined my mapping until now:

```
{
    "WfNewsEvent": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "en": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "fr": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "french",
                        "search_analyzer": "french_search"
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
            "extfile": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "title": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "en": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "fr": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "french",
                                "search_analyzer": "french_search"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "en": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "fr": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "french",
                                "search_analyzer": "french_search"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "en": {
                                "type": "attachment"
                            },
                            "fr": {
                                "type": "attachment",
                                "analyzer": "french",
                                "search_analyzer": "french_search"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "gallery": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "title": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "en": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "fr": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "french",
                                "search_analyzer": "french_search"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "en": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "fr": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "french",
                                "search_analyzer": "french_search"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "en": {
                                "type": "attachment"
                            },
                            "fr": {
                                "type": "attachment",
                                "analyzer": "french",
                                "search_analyzer": "french_search"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then my 'attachment' pipeline definition:

```
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "extfile.data.en",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    },
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "extfile.data.fr",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    },
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "gallery.data.fr",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    },
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "gallery.data.fr",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Actually when I'm trying to index a document, ES raises an exception saying that "data" is not an integer. So any help would be greatly welcome!

Best regards,
Thierry